# Eclipse and VisualVM: what main class for run configuration when using struts?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts-1, visualvm

I'm trying to configure a run VisualVM configuration in Eclipse IDE.

In the Run Configurations Main tab, I set the Project name and the VisualVM Launcher.

If I use as Main class:

```
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

I obtain `A Java Exception has occurred.`

As I'm using `Struts 1`, I tried also

```
  org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
```

but the webapp doesn't run (VisualVM starts).

What main class for run configuration I have to use?